# find max sum in array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a working solution for my problem but now I want to improve it.

Consider the array

```
3,4,5,9,1,2,8
```

I need to find the max difference between two elements at position `i` and `j` such that `i < j` that is I want to find max difference between two elements where the 2nd element comes after 1st element.

In the input I gave the answer is `7` because `8-1 = 7` and `8` is after `1`.

The program works but when I have a very large array it takes lot of time. Can we improve on it?

```
function fMax($arr) 
{
        $sum = $arr[1] - $arr[0];

        for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) 
        {
                for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arr);$j++) 
                {
                        if($sum < $arr[$j] - $arr[$i]) 
                        {
                                $sum = $arr[$j] - $arr[$i];
                        }
                }
        }
        return $sum;
}
```

Thanks a lot to all the answers. I have used the code by codeaddict and it works fast.

Comment: Can you display the output of your array too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach is `O(N^2)` you can improve it to `O(N)`.

You are comparing each element with every other element. Instead you can keep track of the max difference and min element seen so far.

So every time you test a new element you see

- if its difference with the current
  min will give a better max sum if so
  update the max sum and
- if that number is less than the min
  so far you update the min.

PHP function:

```
function ImprovedFindMax($arr) {
    // initial max sum.
    $sum = $arr[1] - $arr[0];

    // initial min.
    $min = $arr[0];

    // iterate for every other ele starting from 2nd.
    for($i=1;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
            // if this ele give larger sum then update sum.
        if($arr[$i] - $min > $sum) {
            $sum = $arr[$i] - $min;
        }

            // if this ele is smaller than min..update min.
        if($arr[$i] < $min) {
            $min = $arr[$i];
        }
    }

    // return $sum which will be the max sum.
    return $sum;
}
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/c0dJc)

Answer (score 5):

One iteration, track the minimum and the maxdiff.  At each element, if the value is less than the minimum, set the minimum to the value; else, if the value - minimum is greater than maxdiff, set the maxdiff to that difference.  Turns it from an O(n^2) to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I haven't tested it.

```
$arr = array(3,4,5,9,1,2,8);

$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$maxdiff = 0;

foreach($arr as $i) {
  if ($i < $min) {
    $min = $i;
  }

  if ($maxdiff < $i - $min) {
    $maxdiff = $i - $min;
  }
}

echo "maxdiff: {$maxdiff}\n";
```

Comment: What if `input array = [-1 , -2]` ?